# Coding First and Follow sets in a CFG

Tags: python, context-free-grammar

```
COMPUTING First[A]
------------------

// Procedure computeFirst
//
// Input: productions P_1, P_2, ..., P_m where P_i = A::=X_1 X_2 X_3 ...X_n
//    with no alternations allowed in the productions.
//
// Output: Computes first of a term or nonterm accounting for nullability
// and multiple productions for the same nonterm.
//
//  First is an array indexed by a terminal or
//  nonterminal and its value is a set of terminals and/or \epsilon.
//
// First[A] for nonterminal A is the set of all possible tokens that 
//    can occur as the first token of a sentence derived from A.
// First[A] for terminal A is simply the set { A }.
//
// Compute the first sets for all tokens from productions P_1, P_2, ..., P_m
//  where no production contains an alternation
//
// CALLS: computeFirstOfList(X_1, X_2, ... X_n)
procedure computeFirst({P_1, P_2, ...P_m})  // works on a list of productions
    // initial value for the First of anything
    foreach A \elemof TERMS do First[A] = {A} 
    foreach A \elemof NONTERMS do First[A] = {} 

    // loop until nothing new happens updating the First sets
    while stillchanging any First[A] do
        foreach production P_i = A::=X_1, X_2, ... X_n do
             First[A] <- First[A] \union computeFirstOfList(X_1, X_2, ... X_n)
        end foreach
    end while
end

// Procedure computeFirstOfList
//
// Computes the First of a rhs rather than just a token!
//
// This computes the set of tokens that can occur as the first
// token of a sentence derived from this rhs (right hand side) of
// of production.  That is X_1, X_2, ... X_n is a concatenation of
// terminals and nonterminals often found on the right hand side
// of a production.  This is nontrivial because some of the leading
// nonterminals on the rhs can go to epsilon.
//
// REFS: First[X_i]  (does not use Follow)
//
procedure computeFirstOfList(X_1, X_2, ... X_n)
    Tmp = {}
    k=0
    do
          k++
          Tmp <- Tmp \union First[X_k]-{\epsilon}
    while k<n & \epsilon isin First[X_k]

    // \epsilon only if X_1, X_2, ... X_n -> \epsilon
    // Note: this test can only possibly work if k==n:
    if \epsilon isin First[X_k] then Tmp <- Tmp \union {\epsilon}

    return Tmp
end

Note:

1. IMPORTANT: if grammar has no \epsilon then the procedure
   computeFirstOfList(X_1, X_2, ... X_n) simply returns First[X_1] 

2. since \epsilon is removed when adding to First inside the do/while
\epsilon can only appear when the entire argument list can be
replaced by \epsilon (called this production is called NULLABLE). 

3. First Sets can contain \epsilon as an element.  Follow Sets cannot as we'll see.

4. Conceptually, computeFirst generates a relation of the form:
First[A] = First[\alpha] \union First[\beta] \union ... \union { \epsilon },
for each production where A occurs on the left hand side (lhs).
This is based on the next point.

5. Conceptually, computeFirstOfList generates a relation of the form:
computeFirstOfList(X_1, X_2, ... X_n) = First[\alpha] \union First[\beta]
\union ... \union { \epsilon } where terms are added based on if
all of the terms before it in the rhs are nullable.
```

I'm trying to create this pseudo-code in python. This concerns First/Follow sets in a Context Free Grammar. The issue i face is that in computeFirst, it says that the loop proceeds for each production which leads me to assume that a single production will be sent into computeFirstOfList. But in that function, it looks like it loops through multiple functions as k < n. I also don't understand what this line does.

```
Tmp <- Tmp \union First[X_k]-{\epsilon}
```

Does this line mean

```
union(tmp,First[k])
```

or

```
union(First[k],epsilon)
```

I don't really understand. I still have to make the union function as well and I was hoping to get some guidance. Here is my code

```
NONTERMS = ['S','E','I','A','T','O','M','F']
TERMS = ['+','-','*','(',')','n','e']
epsilon='e'
FIRST ={}
grammar = {'E':[['T','I'],[epsilon]],
           'I':[['A','T','I'],[epsilon]],
           'A':[['+'],['-']],
           'T':[['F','O']],
           'O':[['M','F','O'],[epsilon]],
           'M':[['*']],
           'F':[['(','E',')'],[epsilon]]}


def computeFirst(g):
    for a in TERMS:
        FIRST[a]=set(a)

    for i in NONTERMS:
        FIRST[i]=set()

    for times in g:
        for key in g:
            Updating= True
            while Updating:
                tmp=FIRST[key].copy()
                for production in g[key]:
                    z=computeFirstOfList(production)
                    FIRST[key].update(FIRST[key].union(z))
                if tmp==FIRST[key]:
                    Updating=False

def computeFirstOfList(p):

    tmp=set()
    k=0
    n=len(p)
    while k<n:
        if(p[k]) in NONTERMS:
            tmp.update(tmp.union(FIRST[p[k]].difference(set(epsilon))))
        k+=1

    return tmp

computeFirst(grammar)
print(FIRST)
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The code is pseudo-code in the images and I thought it would be way too large to post in a question if I did it directly. How should I have done it?

Comment: IMO it's not too long. Besides, the maximum number of lines of code that will be displayed at one time is limited here, and scrollbars will appear automatically for really long snippets.

Comment: I've changed the format

Comment: That's better. However it's still unclear what the pseudo-code means because it's using some kind of unknown/undefined syntax. For example, what does `\identifier` signify?

Comment: I don't see it in the code. If you mean \epsilon. It basically means null as in the term for a CFG

Comment: I was only indicating the general format. There's several different such as `\elemof` and `\union`. How do you expect others to help convert what you have into real code if the terms and syntax used in the pseudo code aren't concretely defined?

Comment: Elemof is "element of" I assumed. It just belongs to the list. Union is a function I have to make to combine two dictionaries

Comment: Why don't you just use python sets? Anyway, for two sets A and B, A-B means "everything that's in A and not in B". Python sets implement that operator, and also | for union and |= for union update. Although you could easily find a more efficient solution.

Comment: Yes, someone in the answers suggested sets which I will do. But I'm still confused on what productions do I send to computeFirstOfList?

Comment: You send one production. computeFirstOfList iterates over the right-hand side of the production, as indicated by the pseudocode.

Comment: Then what is k and n in computeFirstOfList because if I send a single production, there is nothing to iterate over

Comment: `n` is the number of symbols on the right hand side of the production and `k` is the symbol you are currently working on in the loop.

Comment: You might find this algorithm easier to understand if you try it yourself with a piece of paper. You could compute the FIRST set in a couple of minutes. Keep in mind what the FIRST set actually means: it is not some mysterious mathematical concept. It's simply the set of terminals which could be the first terminal in an expansion of the non-terminal, plus ε if the expansion could be empty.

Comment: I just have trouble programming it, I know what FIRST/FOLLOW does. I've updated the code but don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: 1. An empty production should be written as `[]`. Epsilon is not a thing. 2. Your logic for setting Updating is completely wrong. Try it on paper and you'll see, I hope. 3. You're not handling epsilon correctly in computeFirstOfList. You stop the iteration when you find a symbol whose FIRST set doesn't contain epsilon. If you get to the end of the RHS, you need to add epsilon. Also: `FIRST[key].update(FIRST[key].union(z))` is redundant. Use `FIRST[key].update(z)` or `FIRST[key] = FIRST[key].union(z)`. No need to do both. Personally, I'd just write `FIRST[key] |= z`.

Answer (score 0):

> `Tmp <- Tmp \union First[X_k]-{\epsilon}`

It means

```
tmp = set()
tmp = tmp.union(first[x[k]].difference({epsilon})) # first should be dict of set
```

I suggest:

```
def computeFirst(g):
    for a in TERMS:
        FIRST[a]={a}

    for i in NONTERMS:
        FIRST[i]=set()
```

Comment: How does tmp= set() work in python? And am I sending a single production or all the productions for some 'X' into computeFirstOfList?

Comment: It is python. assign `tmp` with an empty set

Comment: Can you check my updated code and correct it? I still can't seem to get this working

Comment: Does `'E':[['T','I'],[epsilon]]` mean `E ::= TI | e`?

Comment: Hi @AleiusN, how is the expected output (from your case) supposed to be?

Comment: "First" which is a dictionary should show the terminals that the non-terminals come "first" to